# Rundeck Resource.xml in github

Tags: rundeck

Is anyone configured Rundeck having its Reource.xml file in Github and pull it from there.Actually i need configuration settings.
My setup is like i have on Rundeck App connected to external DB where it stores all rundeck info(including Projects).

I have followed the below link but did not succeed 
https://docs.rundeck.com/2.6.1/administration/managing-node-sources.html#configuration

NA

Expected should be like: Rundeck automatically pull resource.xml from the github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GIT plugin for that:

1) Go to: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin

2) Download the .jar file from https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin/releases

3) Put the .jar file on RDECK_BASE/libext/ directory (WAR based installation) or /var/lib/rundeck/libext (RPM/DEB based installation).

4) Go to Project Settings > Edit Nodes > Configure Nodes (Button up on right) > Add Source (Green Button) > Click on + Git / Resource Model and fill all information.

Tip: Make sure that the first field point to an empty directory to works.